# Javafx onMouseclicked

Tags: java, javafx

I have a main class that sets the scene and stage

```
public class MediaPlayer extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Main-UI.fxml"));
        stage.setTitle("Media Player");
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

I also have a controller class where i implement all most my function and ect . For some reason my setOnMouseClicked do not seem to work. Is this because it is not the same file that calls the stage.show()

Here is an example of the function the mouse event does not work.

```
private void setMediaViews(){
        String path = "E:" + File.separator + "Videos" +  File.separator + "UFC.205.PPV.Alvarez.vs.McGregor.HDTV.x264-Ebi.mp4";

        media = new Media(new File(path).toURI().toString());
        player = new MediaPlayer(media);
        view = new MediaView(player);
        VBox vbox = new VBox();
        Slider slider = new Slider();
        vbox.getChildren().add(slider);

        videoMediaCont.setCenter(view);
        videoMediaCont.setBottom(vbox);

        player.play();

        player.setOnReady(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                int w = player.getMedia().getWidth();
                int h = player.getMedia().getHeight();


                view.setFitWidth(900);
                vbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
                vbox.setMinHeight(50);

                slider.setMaxSize(900,50);
                slider.setMin(0.0);
                slider.setValue(0.0);
                slider.setMax(player.getTotalDuration().toSeconds());
                slider.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                        player.seek(Duration.seconds(slider.getValue()));
                    }

                });

            }
        });

        player.currentTimeProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Duration>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Duration> observable, Duration oldValue, Duration current) {
                slider.setValue(current.toSeconds());
            }
        });


    }
```

Any help would be great thank you.

Comment: *"Is this because it is not the same file that calls the stage.show()"* I doubt that. Did you declare the controller class in the FXML? Do you get an Error Message at startup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that you try to change the value of the slider, as mentionned in [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/slider.htm) replaces your "OnMouseClicked" event by :

```
slider.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> ov,
                           Number old_val, Number new_val) { 

            player.seek(Duration.seconds((double) new_val);

        }});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply i implemented you code but still does not work. It is like as if the slider was disable from use. Noting when i hover over or noting .

Comment: I figured out i have 3 tab panes for diffrent views  it seems any component inside the tabs will not interact . Any ideas why

Comment: @AmyTeresaHyland I know I'm quite late with this one, but there's GUI interactions that work without `setEditable(true)` (such as button presses) and there's GUI interactions that don't (such as text field input). Maybe slider movement falls in the second category?